# How to make a request to get minimum data from server?

Tags: python-2.7, http, download, request, urllib2

I want to make a **HTTP request**, so that I get minimum data from the server. For eg : If the user device is a mobile, the server will send less data.

I was doing this in *python* ::

```
req = urllib2.Request(__url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

But it still takes some time to download all this. 
If it helps this is the domain from which I want to download pages : https://in.bookmyshow.com

Is there any other way so that I can download a page, quickly with minimum data? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use request for upload files get datas example for get cookies:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://in.bookmyshow.com')
print r.cookies.get_dict()
```

or for upload file:

```
import requests

file = {'file':('filename.txt', open('filename.txt', 'r'), multipart/from-data)}
data = {
      "ButtonValueNameInHtml" : "Submit",
}
r = requests.post('https://in.bookmyshow.com', files=file, data=data)
```

replace in.bookmyshow.com by your own url

you can do many Thigs With requests

Comment: I don't want to upload any file. I just want to download some pages as quickly as possible. Time is a deciding factor for me (the data downloaded is not). So I just want my code to boost up.

Comment: requests is the best way to download pages quickly , better then urlllib2 faster and easy to use